# I need help in creating a Lights Game in Java

Tags: java

I have to write a GUI program to play a lights game. This game should display 6 lights, include a menu bar.

This is how far I have gotten so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LightsGame extends JFrame{

LightsPanel lightPnl = new LightsPanel();

JButton switchButton[] = new JButton[6];

private LightsGame(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lights Game");

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
    this.getContentPane().add(labelPanel);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Switch on all the Lights");
    labelPanel.add(label);  

    //LightsPanel lightPnl = new LightsPanel();

    //Code for buttons:
    for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++){
        switchButton[k] = new JButton("Light " + k );
        buttonPanel.add(switchButton[k]);
    }

    frame.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

    frame.add(lightPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //lightPnl.add(light1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       

    frame.setVisible(true); //Displays the frame
    frame.pack(); //Makes the frame as big as it needs to be.


}//LightsGame()

private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

     if( e.getSource() == switchButton[0])  // toggle lights controlled by button 0

        //Switch the light on or off
        lightPnl.toggleLight();
    }//actionPerformed

}//ButtonHandler

private class MenuHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Stop the Program
        System.exit(0);
    }//ActionPerformed

}//MenuHandler

public static void main(String[] args){

    //JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");  // ?
    LightsGame game = new LightsGame();


}//main

 }//LightsGame
```

and I am using this LightsPanel class (that needs work too):

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

 public class LightsPanel extends JPanel{

//Background color
private final Color backClr = Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
//Outline color
outlineClr = Color.BLACK,
//Color of the light when it is on
onClr = Color.YELLOW,
//Color of the light when it is off
offClr = Color.GRAY;

private boolean switchedOn;    //  ?
    boolean[] array = new boolean[6];   

public LightsPanel(){
    super(); 
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 200));
    boolean[] switchedOn = new boolean[6];  //  ?
    //switchedOn = false;       

}//LightsPanel()

public void paintComponent(Graphics gc){
    super.paintComponent(gc);

    Graphics2D l = (Graphics2D)gc;

    //Draw the background
    setBackground(backClr);

    //Draw the light
    if (switchedOn)
        l.setColor(onClr);
    else
        l.setColor(offClr);
        l.fillOval(75, 75, 50, 50);

    //Draw the outline of the light 
    l.setColor(outlineClr);
    l.drawOval(75, 75, 50, 50);

}//paintComponent   

public void toggleLight() {

//Change the state of the light
if(switchedOn)
    switchedOn = false;
else
    switchedOn = true; 

//Redraw the panel
repaint();

}//toggleLight

public void allLightsOn() {

}//allLightsOn
 }//LightsPanel
```

Right now I am stuck trying to make a loop to display 6 lights and have them work with 6 buttons. I cannot get the buttons to show up either. I need to add buttons to the buttonPanel but I'm not sure how to do that.

My buttons should toggle and correspond to certain lights..

```
Button 0 : lights 0, 2
Button 1 : lights 1, 3
Button 2 : lights 0, 1, 2, 3, 5
Button 3 : lights 0, 1, 2, 4, 5
Button 4 : lights 2, 4
Button 5 : lights 3, 5
```

If anyone is willing or has time to help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: as of right now I'm not all that worried about the menu bar. What I am struggling with is getting the lights and buttons displayed and to work.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're not adding any buttons to anything...

You have this great loop, which seems to make sense to build your logic here...

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++){
    switchButton[k] = new JButton("Light" + k );
}
```

For example...

```
for (int k = 0; k < switchButton.length; k++){
    switchButton[k] = new JButton("Light" + k );
    buttonPane.add(switchButton[k]);
}
```

Now the next time you need to attach some kind of handler to the button so you can change the light state accordingly...

For this, you will need to take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Personally, I would make the `LightsPanel` responsible for a single light and simply create as many instance of this panel as you need.  Then you could simply create a `switch` method which turns the light on or off as required...

Comment: Thank You for that! I was so close! I had something like that before but it wouldn't compile for me so I took it out. Thank you! I will see what I can do with the link for how to use buttons.

Comment: Been looking at this on how to use buttons and action listeners. I have a button handler which implements an action listener do i use that?

Comment: As long as the button handler is doing what you want for each button then that wound sound reasonable

Comment: Alright so I have it "toggling" each light then right? How do I make more lights show up? right now there is one light and 6 buttons that dont do anything.

Comment: This is why I would recommend that you have a single light pane which only has a single light.  Then create as many instances of it as you need, associated with a `JButton` which would be used to simply toggle that panel on and off

Comment: Ok, I understand it seems easier to do it that way. So how do I do that? Do I already have a single light pane with a single light on it? My toggle method needs work too (That I don't know how to do). How do I get that to have an integer parameter so it will correspond to the lights?     I edited the code in the LightsGame and LightsPanel too.

Comment: You need to know two things.  Which button was clicked and which light it is associated with it.  You then need some kind of `toggle` method that will take the "light" to be changed (which yours currently doesn't)